# AngularJS HTTP Response Missing Values?

Tags: angularjs, json, response, angular-http

You read that right, this is AngularJS, the old one.

I have an Angular $http.post that returns an object with various values including a fairly large dictionary of more objects that map to a bunch of fields on a spreadsheet.

The magic: 
If I debug the backend (.NET) and look at the object being returned all is well and as expected. If I log out the res.data object right after it is returned in the JS callback there is one particular (possibly more) string value within that dictionary of objects I mentioned that is set from "Some text" to "". No errors, no warnings...
But get this... if I look at the response in Fiddler THE VALUE IS THERE.

The discovery: 
If I do a Request for only that Dictionary of Objects rather than it plus other data the value does indeed appear. Cool, so I can work around this... But WHY?

Why would this happen? Is there some size cap on response objects to Angulars $http.post? I am passing in no options to the post and I cannot find any info on this.

Thanks for any ideas!

UPDATE: (Code has been requested)

```
$http.post(baseUrl + "TESTCompData?p1=" + p1 + "&c1=" + c1).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
```

The dictionary object I'm referring to:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,object>> ControlData;
```

The object in question:

```
{txt_SomeTexty: {
LineItemDataID=998,
LineItemMetaDataID=325,
SectionID=11,
Value=Some Text for XX (not a abc): $999,999,999}}
```

Value here comes in blank.

Comment: Added some code that could be useful.

Comment: The `.post` method takes two required arguments, `url` and `data`, and one optional argument, `config`. Perhaps you should be using the `.get` method. For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Shortcut methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out though.

Turns out I was just accidentally clearing the field during a transformation method I had.

But what I don't understand: I was console.log'ing the object BEFORE this took place yet I saw it changed there. See I expected the logged object to be what it was when the response was returned (since that's where the log was) but somehow it isn't... it's the updated version.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));` to see the response object when it was returned.